# Slicing and Dicing Strings with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm interested in a Regex pattern that will jump to the first non whitespace character, return that index and then from there the next whitespace character, and return that index.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is pull a word out of a string. But I'd also like to preserve indexes because I need to rebuild that string without the word we just pulled out.

Something of this sort:

```
var start = txt.search(/\S/); //this gets the index of the first non whitespace character
var end = txt.search(/\s/); //this gets the index of the first whitespace character
var word = txt.slice(start,end); //get the word
txt = txt.slice(end); //update txt to hold the rest of the string
```

The problem with that implementation is if the first whitespace character comes BEFORE the first non whitespace character, we get undesired results.

If .search had a start index that'd be super helpful, but other than that I am stumped.

Trying to word this a bit better:

I need the index of the first non whitespace character, and then the index of the first whitespace character that comes after the first nonwhitespace character. This would allow me to get a single word from a string.

Comment: Pull a word out by what condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you just really want to take the words out of the sentence, you have two options:
1. trim the sentence, that is easy but since you want to preserve the first sentence. There is the next options.
2. split the sentence in an array

```
var txt = " this is a sentece ";
var words = txt.split(/\W/);
while(words.indexOf("") !== -1) {
    words.splice(words.indexOf(""), 1);
}
```

now **words** is `["this", "is", "a", "sentece"]`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var string = "      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    matches = [],
    re = /\S+/g,
    match;

while (match = re.exec(string)){
    matches.push(match);
}

/* matches = [
    [0: "Lorem"
     index: 6
     input: "      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy te..."],
    [0: "Ipsum"
     index: 12
     input: "      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy te..."],

     ...

]; */
```